# Swift: Sort Array of Object Property While Keeping Order Intact

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting

as the long name of this question suggests, I am trying to sort an array of objects by those object's properties, but I am having issues with the order in which the array is returned. Basically, my database structure has each date, in order, and then entries under ascending numbers under that date's directory. Below is a visual representation of the structure:

```
Balances
   -11/7/17
        -0
            -name: "Name 1 Here"
        -1
            -name: "Name 2 Here"
        -2
            -name: "Name 3 Here"
   -11/8/17
        -0
            -name: "Name 1 Here"
        -1
            -name: "Name 2 Here"
        -2
            -name: "Name 3 Here"
   -11/9/17
        -0
            -name: "Name 1 Here"
        -1
            -name: "Name 2 Here"
        -2
            -name: "Name 3 Here"
```

When I retrieve the data from the database through a SingleValueEvent and add it to an array of custom objects, the data in the array for some reason gets out of order, and doesn't stay in the exact order as the data is stored in the database. To solve this problem, I tried to use the following code to order the array:

```
self.tableArray = self.tableArray.sorted(by: { $0.date < $1.date })

self.tableArray.sort(by: { (object1, object2) -> Bool in
    if object1.date != object2.date {
        return object1.date < object2.date
    } else {
    return object1.date < object2.date
    }
})
```

The array returned after using either of the two lines of code is sorted by each object's date, but the order of each of the items under the date in the database is screwed up. I know this is kind of confusing, which is why I have included a visual representation below which I hope will help.

```
Original Array:

 Item 1: 

  date: 11/14/17
  name: Name 1

 Item 2: 

  date: 11/13/17
  name: Name 1

 Item 3: 

  date: 11/13/17
  name: Name 2

 Item 4: 

  date: 11/7/17
  name: Name 1

Sorted Array:

 Item 1: 

  date: 11/7/17
  name: Name 1

 Item 2: 

  date: 11/13/17
  name: Name 2

 Item 3: 

  date: 11/13/17
  name: Name 1

 Item 4: 

  date: 11/14/17
  name: Name 1
```

Thanks!

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. The sorted array sorted exactly the way you asked it to be sorted (to the extent that your sorting code makes any sense at all). What is "screwed up" about it?

Comment: What is screwed up is that while it is sorting the objects in the array by date, it is screwing up the order of the objects under a date, if you see what I mean.

Comment: I don't see what you mean (by "objects under a date").

Comment: If you look in the database structure, you have a date, and then you have items under that date whose names are numbers. Basically, the order of those numbers is not retained, while in the database they are in numerical order, like 0, 1, 2, etc, that order gets messed up after sorting the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a few reasons, the way it is serialised or sorted in storage - without specific insight into if you're using CoreData, Real, SQLite or other...

TL; DR, if you want to ensure the order is exactly as per what you want, and it looks like you have multiple sorting criteria, define that criteria as an attribute. You cannot always guarantee persistence will maintain the ordering, so build it into the schema.

I.e.

```
{name, date}
```

Add an extra attribute

```
{name, date, order}.
```

The order property can be globally unique or just unique within items of that date.

You can either sort twice (with the second sort being stable), or  better yet define a comparison that first compares by date, and then by the other.

```
self.tableArray.sort(by: { (object1, object2) -> Bool in
    if object1.date != object2.date {
        return object1.date < object2.date
    } else {
        return object1.order < object2.order
    }
})
```

Comment: Hi Mitchell, I will have to test this idea out tomorrow and see if it works, though it seems like it should work. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. You could even think of it like an 'Id' or "customer_id", even core data has an auto increment if you just want .

Comment: Hi Mitchell, it turns out I was already storing the order variable in the array, I just wasn't using it for this specific purpose. I tried out your code and it worked flawlessly. Thanks so much for your help in getting this issue resolved.